# Set delay in mootools chain

Tags: mootools, delay, chain

i've been trying to set a mootools chain to apply it then in a site. So, i've done it but, still... i need to set a delay on the beggining of sequence, i mean like, wait for 5 seconds before everything starts, i've tried to set .delay(5000) but just doesn't work out, pleeaaase help. thanks, here's the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Probando chain de mootools</title>
    <script src="mootools.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>


var ClaseChainEfecto = new Class({
    //implemento chain
    Implements: Chain,

    initialize: function(){
        this.efecto1 = new Fx.Tween('elem1', {
            property: 'opacity',
            duration: 1000,
            onComplete: function(){
                this.callChain();
            }.bind(this)
        });
        this.efecto2 = new Fx.Tween('elem2', {
            property: 'opacity',
            duration: 1000
        });
    },

    efectos: function(){
        this.chain(
            function(){ this.efecto1.start(1,0); },
            function(){ this.efecto2.start(0,1); }
        );
        this.callChain();
    }
});

window.addEvent("domready", function(){
    miClaseChainEfecto = new ClaseChainEfecto();
    miClaseChainEfecto.efectos();
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.miestilo1{
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: 333399;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    margin: 15px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
.miestilo2{
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: 333399;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 14pt;
    margin: 15px;
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="elem1" class="miestilo1">
HOLA!! estoy probando chain. Pongo esta capa con más texto para que se vea!!
</div>
<div id="elem2" class="miestilo2">
Esto es un segundo elemento. Que también tendrá su efecto!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some advice to increase your chances of getting an answer: 1. Format your question better (capitals, paragraphs). 2. Make a JSfiddle out of your code. No one likes reading someone else's code, especially when you give _everything_, including CSS and HTML boilerplate that has nothing to do with the question. 3. Talk to us like you're an adult. “I mean like” and “pleaaaaaaase” are wrong ways to do this. Basically, it all boils down to: write something you yourself would agree spending enough minutes on  ;)

Comment: just do `this.callChain();` -> `this.callChain.delay(5000, this);`